# When I am passing a variable through a link to another HTML file, the CSS Configurations disappear. Any reason why this is occurring?

Tags: html, css, variables, hyperlink

So I have an HTML document, and it is necessary to pass variables.
The document is called example.html, and when I run it by itself, the CSS and design is all fine. However if I go to example.html/?x=4&y=2 the page processes the variables and everything as it should, but the design goes away (as in, I get a plain text boring website).

Not sure if it will help, but just for your information, I am using Bootstrap for this, so if that has anything to do with it.

Edit: The problem occurs when I start the slash at the end of the link. For clarification, example.html works well, but if I do example.html/ all of the Bootstrap CSS, and whatnot goes away and I'm left with base HTML code.

Edit, relevant section of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Bootstrap Ex.</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="defunkt-facebox-cbe32e1/src/facebox.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="TableSorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
</head>


<h5 id = "title"> </h5>
 <script>
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }

 document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = 'List of bugs on ' + vars.taskTitle + '.';

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show some code related to your question?

Comment: What kind of code do you need? I'm not sure if the code itself will help. It has to do something with the fact that adding extra stuff after the link is taking away the Bootstrap CSS. And yeah, like I mentioned, without the '/' at the end of the URL, everything works fine.

Comment: The code might help, how the bootstrap css is referenced? Relative or absolute path?

Comment: <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"> 

As shown, I used a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

I know when i do the same thing in php i do not put a / try it without the / and see what happens

example.html?x=4&y=2

Comment: I tried it and I'm getting a different result, but the CSS and bootstrap components are still not there.

Comment: Show us the full page code and we may be able to help, i have a feeling your divs or something similar may be getting messed up by some process you are doing after you retrieve the variables from your address bar. Pastebin is fine, or edit or your original post

Comment: Okay, I've done some more debugging, and got this to work. But now there's another similar problem. This time, I'm trying to load a JSONObject, and when I load the page, the CSS, and whatnot again don't display, and the browser is continuously "connecting"/loading, without ever finishing.

Answer (score 0):

'/' in the url denote a change to a different file, so running it as example.html/?x=4y=2, is telling the browser to try to find a file location of ?x=4&y=2, wherever your url is being entered change it to example.html?x=4&y=2. My knowledge on the topic is a bit shaky, but I believe this is your problem